# In Fortran 90, does the size of a module affect the performance of a subroutine, other than the time required for allocation?

Tags: fortran, fortran90

In Fortran 90, does the number of variables defined in a module affect the performance of execution of a subroutine?

Suppose that I have some variables defined in a module, and I am using all of those variables in my subroutine. Now, I add other variables in my module, but **do not use or reference them** in my subroutine.

Does it have any effect on access speed? It would surely affect the time required for the allocation of all variables at the beginning of execution, but does it have any other effects?

Maybe there could be different consequences with different compilers. In that case, I am using `gfortran`, and let's keep it strictly to that.

Comment: If you are seriously concerned about this issue why haven't you made any measurements ?

Comment: I am planning to, I am just discouraged by the fact that Fortran is extremely efficient and my computer is very fast :D

Comment: There can always be subtle issues with exact memory placement affecting some parts of code. The order in which you access the variables can play a role and it will depend on cache misses. No definite answer can be made in general.